# Angular JS directive is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a simple angularjs custom directive but I seem to be missing something. The code is available at

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="menuDirective.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <hello-world></hello-world>
</body>

</html>
```

**directive**

```
     (function(){
  angular.module('helloWorld',[])
  .directive('helloWorld',helloWorld);
  function helloWorld()
  {
    return {
      replace:true,
      restrict: 'AE',
      template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>'
    }
  }
})();
```

**app**

```
      (function()
{
  "use strict"
   angular.module("myApp",['helloWorld']);
})();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zywA3bazXzdd5lERYdxk

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong version of angular, change the included script to:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```